# Calculating total of a ListView column WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm creating an EPOS system for a bar, for my own project just to test my skills.

I've come into a problem, I've managed to put all products in a `WrapPanel` and when clicked ive also managed to get them to show in a ListView control.

However, I cannot seem to get the total to show in a label below the ListView, essentially, each time a product is added to the ListView i want the total to also be updated by adding up all of the prices in the "Price" column and displaying them in a label below. But i cannot even seem to print the total via a button let alone do it automatically.

Here is my code for the button so far.

Don't suggest SubItems as it doesnt work in WPF.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

     decimal total = 0;


     foreach (ListViewItem o in orderDetailsListView.Items)
     {
         total = total + (decimal)(orderDetailsListView.SelectedItems[1]);
     }  
     totalOutputLabel.Content = total;
}
```

Comment: Please post your error ouput.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this below answer to another question of yours on this same program that you deleted before I could post it. It covers updating the price but it also covers a lot more (using information that was in the deleted question).

---

First of all, if you want the screen to update when the items in the list are updated you must make the class implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public class OrderDetailsListItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private decimal _price;
    private int _quantity;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _name) return;
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _price) return;
            _price = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return _quantity; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _quantity) return;
            _quantity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now when the Price or Quantity is changed it will let the bindings know that the item was changed.

Next the reason that your `if (OrderItem.Contains(` caused duplicate items to show up is you must implement `Equals(` (and preferably `GetHashCode()`) for things like `Contains(` to work.

```
public class OrderDetailsListItem : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEquatable<OrderDetailsListItem>
{
    //(Snip everything from the first example)

    public bool Equals(OrderDetailsListItem other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        return string.Equals(_name, other._name);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as OrderDetailsListItem);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (_name != null ? _name.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

Another point, don't do `OrderItem.CollectionChanged +=` in your button click, you will be creating extra event calls every collection changed event. Just set it one in the constructor and that is the only even subscription you need. However, there is a even better collection to use, [`BindingList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and its `ListChanged` event. A BindingList will raise the ListChange event in all the situations that ObserveableCollection raises CollectionChanged but in addition it will also raise the event when any item in the collection raises the INotifyPropertyChanged event.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    _orderItem = new BindingList<OrderDetailsListItem>();
    _orderItem.ListChanged += OrderItemListChanged;
    InitializeComponent();
    GetBeerInfo();

    //You will see why all the the rest of the items were removed in the next part.
}

private void OrderItemListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TotalPrice = OrderItem.Select(x => x.Price).Sum();
}
```

Lastly, I would bet you came from a Winforms background. WPF is based around binding a lot more than winforms, I used to write code a lot like what you are doing before I really took that point in. All of those assignments to labels and collections should be done in the XAML with bindings, this allows for things like the INotifyPropertyChanged events to automatically update the screen without needing a function call.

Here is a simple recreation of your program that runs and uses bindings and all of the other things I talked about.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:myNamespace ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Content="{x:Static myNamespace:GlobalVariables._amstelProductName}" Click="amstelBeerButton_Click"/>


            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalPrice, StringFormat=Total: {0:c}}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding OrderItem}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Price, StringFormat=c}" Header="Price"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Quantity, StringFormat=N0}" Header="Quantity"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TotalPriceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "TotalPrice", typeof (decimal), typeof (MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(decimal)));

        private readonly BindingList<OrderDetailsListItem> _orderItem;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            _orderItem = new BindingList<OrderDetailsListItem>();
            _orderItem.ListChanged += OrderItemListChanged;
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            GetBeerInfo();
        }

        public BindingList<OrderDetailsListItem> OrderItem
        {
            get { return _orderItem; }
        }

        public decimal TotalPrice
        {
            get { return (decimal) GetValue(TotalPriceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TotalPriceProperty, value); }
        }

        private void GetBeerInfo()
        {
            OrderItem.Add(new OrderDetailsListItem
            {
                Name = "Some other beer",
                Price = 2m,
                Quantity = 1
            });
        }

        private void OrderItemListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TotalPrice = _orderItem.Select(x => x.Price).Sum();
        }

        private void amstelBeerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //This variable makes me suspicous, this probibly should be a property in the class. 
            var quantityItem = GlobalVariables.quantityChosen;

            if (quantityItem == 0)
            {
                quantityItem = 1;
            }

            var item = OrderItem.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == GlobalVariables._amstelProductName);

            if (item == null)
            {
                OrderItem.Add(new OrderDetailsListItem
                {
                    Name = GlobalVariables._amstelProductName,
                    Quantity = quantityItem,
                    Price = GlobalVariables._amstelPrice
                });
            }
            else if (item != null)
            {
                item.Quantity = item.Quantity + quantityItem;
                item.Price = item.Price*item.Quantity;
            }
            //The UpdatePrice function is nolonger needed now that it is a bound property.
        }
    }

    public class GlobalVariables
    {
        public static int quantityChosen = 0;
        public static string _amstelProductName = "Amstel Beer";
        public static decimal _amstelPrice = 5;
    }

    public class OrderDetailsListItem : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEquatable<OrderDetailsListItem>
    {
        private string _name;
        private decimal _price;
        private int _quantity;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _name) return;
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public decimal Price
        {
            get { return _price; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _price) return;
                _price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int Quantity
        {
            get { return _quantity; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _quantity) return;
                _quantity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool Equals(OrderDetailsListItem other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
            return string.Equals(_name, other._name);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return Equals(obj as OrderDetailsListItem);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (_name != null ? _name.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just did a test on this, you should make sure you are getting into the event handler by adding a breakpoint. If you are not, make sure you have registered the handler to the click event, e.g.:

```
<Button Name="TestButton" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
```

If you are playing around with WPF I would strongly suggest looking at MVVM and data binding at some point.